# How to read a large text file in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text, read-write

I am having a text file containing 65536 integers. I am writing a C++ program given at below to read this file. But it is not working properly. It is working well for text file with few integers. But not working properly for large file.

```
#include(iostream)

#include(fstream)

using namespace std;

int main() {

 ifstream myReadFile;

 myReadFile.open("FileName.txt");

 char output[1000];

 if (myReadFile.is_open()) {

 while (!myReadFile.eof()) {


    myReadFile >> output;

    cout<<output;


 }

}
myReadFile.close();

system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Please suggest the Solution.

Comment: Why did you tag this C when it is clearly C++? Please don't add spurious language tags.

Comment: Does that code compile? Is that the actual code?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info, then use the debugger. And 65536 lines is a *small* file today (a *large* file would have dozens of gigabytes)

Comment: Why not read one integer at a time ? Just declare your output as an integer.

Comment: Do **not** use formatted input in a `char` array without setting the stream's `width()`! It results in a potential buffer overrun. **Always** set the `width()` before using `stream >> array`, e.g., using `myReadFile >> std::setw(sizeof(output)) >> output`.

Comment: **Always** check your input _after_ reading and do **not** try to use `eof()` to determine if input was successful (it gets set at the wrong times). Instead, use something like `while (stream >> std::setw(sizeof(buffer) >> buffer) { ... }`. I would burn and book teaching use of `eof()` in the way you did as it is clearly written by some incapable of reasoning about code to start with (if it were an actual teacher, well, the solution isn't as simple...).

Answer (score 1):

> read a line each time

```
if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
    char output[1000];

    while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
        // just read one line
        myReadFile.getline(output, 1000);
        cout<<output;
    }
    myReadFile.close();
}
```

Comment: The second occurrence of `1000`   should be `sizeof(output)`

Comment: `output` should be renamed `line` or `buf` or `buffer` for clarity.

Comment: Also looping on `eof()` is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong